# Not Able to Start windows service on windows server 2016 using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to start windows service using Powershell.

Command is `Start-Service -Name 'Log Reader' -Verbose`

I ran above command with evlevated powershell with Admin rights.

But I am getting following

```
Start-Service : Failed to start service 'Log Reader (Log Reader)'.
```

At line:1 char:1

- Start-Service -Name 'Log Reader' -Verbose
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
  ```

On Server it is not working but on local machine, it is working fine.

Please help me here

Comment: If it works on one machine and not on another, the issue is not really with your code, but with the differences between systems, versions, users, permissions, security etc. Those things are therefore not code related and would be better asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/ask).

Comment: If you do decide to ask elsewhere, please ensure that you provide significantly more information. In addition to us having no information about the systems, versions, users, permissions, security etc. they'd also need to know about the 'service', what it does, whether it has dependents etc, and things like whether it's a real service, or one of those processes, created using `nssm` to pretend to be a service.